# Interacting with Bytecode

Tags: evm, bytecode

Is it possible to interact with a smart contract with bytecode only (without ABI)?

If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: No.**

**Long Answer:** If you know the code of the function you want to call (e.g. in case of a ERC20 token) you can compile it again to get its *signature / part of the ABI*.

Then just call the function as you normally would.